# How to handle attached properties events?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, attached-properties

I created an expander style that contains a checkbox in its header. The checkbox state is bound to an attached property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}" x:Key="MyCheckboxExpander">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
               (...)
                   <CheckBox x:Name="ExpanderHeaderChk" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(my:AP.IsChecked)}" />
                (...)
```

I my view, inside the expander I have a stackpanel with a ComboBox.

Whenever the user checks the expander's checkbox, I wan't that the combobox gets the first item selected, on the oher hand whenever the user unchecks it, I wan't that the selecteditem of the combobox be null.

How can I accomplish this? I'm following the MVVM pattern, but since this is more a matter of the view, I'm open to code-behind suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the suggestion provided by @Baboon and I created a custom control with a routed event named **CheckedChanged**, this way I can access it through the view's xaml and code-behind:

```
 [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Expander", Type = typeof(Expander))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_CheckBox", Type = typeof(CheckBox))]
public class MyCustomExpander : Expander
{
    static MyCustomExpander()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomExpander), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomExpander)));
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCustomExpander),
                                     new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    #region Events

    private CheckBox chkExpander = new CheckBox();
    public CheckBox ChkExpander { get { return chkExpander; } private set { chkExpander = value; } }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ExtraButtonClick", 
                                                                                               RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
                                                                                               typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                                                                                               typeof(MyCustomExpander));

    public event RoutedEventHandler CheckedChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(CheckedChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedChangedEvent, this));
    } 

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        CheckBox chk = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_CheckBox") as CheckBox;
        if (chk != null)
        {
            chk.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(OnCheckedChanged);
            chk.Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(OnCheckedChanged);
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

I want to thank to @Baboon and @Vlad for their help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your design is not optimal. You see, you are trying to change the semantics of the `Expander`. The real expander doesn't have the semantics with additional checkbox, so the control you are creating is not an Expander any more.

I would suggest that you switch to a user control (or maybe a custom control, look at your semantics), and expose the needed event in your control's class. The XAML for the user control should be perhaps an expander with a checkbox.

---

Edit: example with UserControl (not tested)

(XAML)

```
<UserControl x:Class="namespace:MyCheckboxExpander">
    <Expander>
        ...
        <Checkbox x:Name="cb"/>
        ...
    </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

(code-behind)

```
public class MyCheckboxExpander : UserControl
{
    MyCheckboxExpander()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cb.Check += OnCheck;
    }

    void OnCheck(object sender, whatever2 args)
    {
        if (CheckboxTriggered != null)
            CheckboxTriggered(new EventArgs<whatever>);
    }

    public event EventArgs<whatever> CheckboxTriggered;
}
```

Comment: It looks like he's using a custom control (!=UserControl)

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. I'll google "custom control expose events" as I don't know much about custom controls...

Comment: @Baboon: the OP seems to try to attach an additional event to an `Expander`. Although this might be technically possible, it's anyway a hack, so the solution would be to honestly create a new user control. Or maybe a custom control.

Comment: @Eduardo: try `UserControl`, that should be simpler.

Comment: It should really be a custom control, he's not grouping functionalities, he's retemplating a control of the framework.

Comment: According to this link http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html, I think I should use a custom control

Comment: @Baboon: well, as my answer states I don't think retemplating the existing Expander is a way to go. Because the control the OP wants to get is basically not an expander. Because expanders don't have an event saying that internal checkbox is flipped. Because expanders don't generally have checkboxes. So, if you expose the checkbox-related things, it's not an expander any more.

Comment: @Vlad, I need the checkbox to stay in the expander's header, can that be done easily? P.S. Thanks for the code ;)

Comment: @Eduardo: Well, relatively easy. With UserControl, it's like in the example code. With custom control, you'll need to define the events in the custom control class and write an appropriate control template.

Comment: @Vlad At this point I'm not sure you really know what a custom control is, or what part contracts are. What he wants is a custom control. You don't need to redefine the events for a custom control, however you can re-route them. For retemplating, you just have to create the parts required by the Expander's contract, and the easiest way to do so is to get a copy of the original template in Blend.

Comment: @Baboon: I am speaking about the semantics. While it's possible technically to derive a new control from Expander, and load it with new semantics, from design point of view it's a separate thing. Mixing the old and the new expanders would violate [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if you're into it. So it requires a separate class, not derive-and-hack the Expander. The "easiest" solution is not always the right solution.

Comment: @Baboon, how can I re-route an event based on my boolean attached property? Can you please submit the code as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is so powerfull framework, that you can solve you problem just using next style for Expander:

```
 <Style x:Key="myExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="PART_CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <ComboBox x:Name="PART_ComboBox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_ComboBox" Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

SAMPLE:

```
<Expander Style="{StaticResource myExpanderStyle}">
            <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                <sys:String>1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>2</sys:String>
                <sys:String>3</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Expander>
```

Just XAML! I like XAML declarativity.

But from MVVM perspective, this approach has one disadvantage - I can't cover this case with unit tests. So, I would prefer:

1. create view model with properties: IsChecked(bound to CheckBox),
   SelectedItem(bound to ComboBox) and Source(ItemsSource for ComboBox) -
   abstration of my real view without any references on controls;
2. write a logic in view model that set or unset SelectedItem depending
   on IsChecked property;
3. cover that logic with unit test (yep, you can
   even start with this point, if you like test first approach).